# Breaking down the sum of two random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, random-variables, independence

Is there a pair of **continuous** and **independent** random variables $X$ and $Y$, such that you can infer the values of $X$ and $Y$ given their sum ? A discrete example would be $X$ uniform on $\{0,2\}$ and $Y$ uniform on $\{3,4\}$, so the sum $X+Y$ (equal to $3,4,5$ or $6$) entirely determines the values of $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: I suspect not, though you might wonder about the sum of special singular distributions (which are continuous but not absolutely continuous)

Comment: Well, if $X$ can take a value $x_0$ such that any value in some neighborhood can also be be taken by $X$, and similarly for $Y$ and $y_0$, then the sum $x_0+y_0$ does not determine $x_0,y_0$ since we could also get that sum via $x_0+\epsilon, y_0-\epsilon$ for small enough $\epsilon$.

Comment: This seems to be impossible: if both are continuous (even in a small region around $x$ and $y$), then there exist infinitely many pairs $X=x+\varepsilon$ and $Y = y-\varepsilon$, which all have the same sum.

Comment: @lulu  - that may work for absolutely continuous distributions, but my hesitation was about about singular distributions which I think have no neighbourhoods fully in the support

Comment: @Henry  Yes, I expect one needs to spell out just what is meant by a continuous distribution.  Lots of sources, [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_distribution#Continuous_probability_distribution), say, take absolute continuity as part of the definition.  Of course, other assumptions are possible.

Comment: Thanks guys ! I was referring to absolutely continuous random variables, i.e. having a density w.r.t. the Lebesgue measure.